# Is "the computers" in "here are the computers that you requested" a subject or object?

Tags: subjects, objects, subject-or-object

I'm a little confused which is the subject and the object in this sentence:

> Here are the computers that you requested.

My guess is that "the computers" is the object and "you" is the subject.

Is that correct?

Comment: It's an inversion, giving the location of the computers and alternating with the uninverted construction "The computers that you requested are here". The post-verbal NP "the computers ..." is subject, as evidenced by the fact that the verb agrees with the NP (cf. "Here **is** the **computer** that you requested").

Comment: Hi @BillJ, Is it safe to assume that all post-verbal NP is a subject?

Comment: If you are referring to just subject-dependent inversion constructions, yes, but not elsewhere.

Comment: Incidentally, within the subordinate relative clause, the relativised element is in object position, and understood as "computers": "Here are the computers [that you requested ___]", where gap is object of "requested" and has "computers" as antecedent.

Comment: Note, too, there is a grammatical concept of [*agent* and *patient*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)). In sentences that aren't inverted, the subject is the agent, and the object is the patient. When a sentence *is* inverted, the subject and object switch places; however, the agent and patient do not. Since we *normally* understand the two to mean the same thing (in more commonly constructed sentences), inverted sentences can cause confusion with the semantic referents of *subject* and *object*.

Comment: Generally speaking, where noun phrases are on both "ends" of the verb "to be", they are regarded as having equivalent status.

Answer (score 1):

"The computers that you requested" is the subject, despite its location in the sentence; this sentence is ascribing the property of being here to the computers. As noted in the comments by BillJ, this becomes obvious when you consider that the verb "to be" agrees with "the computers," not with "here":

> - Here **are** the **computers** that you requested.
> - Here **is** the **computer** that you requested.

Comment: Better to use community wikis for quoted comments.

Comment: I agree with @EdwinAshworth; when you write an answer to an old question that repeats others' comments with little of your own content (without making it a community wiki), it may seem as though you're simply reputation-hunting. I'm sure that that isn't the case, but it can give that appearance.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Will do.